Sample space is independent of itself.
Question
Let $\Omega$ be the sample space. Then we have $\mathbb{P}(\Omega \cap \Omega) = \mathbb{P}(\Omega)\mathbb{P}(\Omega) $. Thus $\Omega$ is independent of itself. This is fine mathematically. But what does it actually mean intuitively. When we say $A$ is independent of $B$, we mean that occurrence or non-occurence of one event doesn't affect the other, so in this sense what does the above mean?

Try to take an example and think. Suppose you are rolling a dice. What is your $\Omega$? What does it mean for the event $\Omega$ to occur? If it occurs, what does it mean for any other event to occur given $\Omega$ has occured?
